# Saxon-HE Java Extension - How to I access the value of a xsl-variable which is passed as a parameter?

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I have created a function using the Saxon documentation which has 3 parameters. The function takes an input string and pads it out to a specific size using an integer and string values.

padStringLeft(inputStr,size,padChar)

If I put this in my XSLT and hard wire the parameters the function works.

```
<debug1><xsl:value-of select="c4j_XSLT_Ext_padStringLeft:padStringLeft('1',4,'0')" /></debug1>
```

The output from the above would be '0001'

When I pass the contents of a XSLT variable however and set a debug / break point in my java function I can see that I'm getting param0 as a lazysequence.

```
<debug2><xsl:value-of select="c4j_XSLT_Ext_padStringLeft:padStringLeft($myvar,4,'0')" /></debug2>
```

[Java function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pthKb.gif)

As my code is attempting to treat it as a string it does not work.

How should I be handling this scenario, how do I access the value or the xsl-variable/param and what if sometimes I want to use a literal string instead of a variable?

```
public class XSLT_Ext_padStringLeft extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition
{

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes()
    {
        return new SequenceType[]{SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING,SequenceType.SINGLE_INTEGER, SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING};
    }

    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName()
    {
        return new StructuredQName("c4j_XSLT_Ext_padStringLeft", "http://com.commander4j.Transformation.XSLT_Ext_padStringLeft", "padStringLeft");
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] arg0)
    {
         return SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression()
    {
           return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
                @Override
                public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
                    
                    String inputStr;
                    try
                    {
                        inputStr = ((StringValue)arguments[0]).getStringValue();
                    } catch (ClassCastException ex)
                    {
                       inputStr = "";   
                    }

                    
                    long size;
                    try
                    {
                        String temp =arguments[1].toString();
                        size = Integer.valueOf(temp);
                    } catch (ClassCastException ex)
                    {
                        size = 1;   
                    }
                    
                    String padStr;
                    try
                    {
                        padStr = ((StringValue)arguments[2]).getStringValue();
                    } catch (ClassCastException ex)
                    {
                        padStr = "";    
                    }
                    
                    String result = inputStr;
                    
                    while (result.length() < size)
                    {
                        result = padStr + result;
                    }

                    return StringValue.makeStringValue(result);
                }
            };
    }

}
```

Thanks

Dave

Comment: It would help if you show us where you declare and bind which value exactly to the variable `$myvar`.

Comment: <xsl:template match="xml">

  <xsl:param name="variant" select="VAR_CODE"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the parameters are passed as instance of the class `net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence`, and you should only use the methods on the interface `Sequence`, rather than examining what particular kind of `Sequence` it is, because that could change in the future.

If you're expecting a singleton sequence (that is, a single item), call `head()` to get the first item in the sequence (this will return null if the sequence is empty). You will then have an instance of `net.sf.saxon.om.Item`. (The `Sequence` might already be an `Item`, because an item is a sequence, but you can't rely on that, and calling `head()` is safer than casting.) If you're expecting a string, you can safely call `getStringValue()` on this item to get the value as a string.

Also note, Saxon uses lazy evaluation wherever possible, which means that the string might not actually be computed until someone asks for its value. This means that innocent-looking calls like `head()` and `getStringValue()` can actually throw exceptions, and you need to be prepared for this.

So in short, you should replace

```
inputStr = ((StringValue)arguments[0]).getStringValue();
```

with

```
inputStr = arguments[0].head().getStringValue();
```

Comment: I have to say I feel rather out of my depth but I will try to ask as few questions as possible. Should I be replacing all my code which needs to aquire argument values including strings in quotes 'literal' params rather than variables. One of my params was a integer and my code seems to have worked for that. Should I revise the syntax as above ? As you mention above a lazy evaulation might trigger an error - is there a example of how to handle that ?

Comment: Is there any training material (books/videos) on the new Saxon Library API ?

Comment: There's very extensive documentation (far too detailed for most people, sadly) but no training material as such. There's an appendix in my XSLT 2.0 reference book, but it's way out of date. I'm afraid you're in territory here where you're expected to work from the Javadoc. The fact that something works doesn't mean you've got it right: it's very easy to find that you're missing cases, like the caller supplying an empty sequence. Error handling usually won't be a problem if you just let the exceptions cause termination in the natural way.

Answer (score 0):

> Also note, Saxon uses lazy evaluation wherever possible, which means that the string might not actually be computed until someone asks for its value. This means that innocent-looking calls like head() and getStringValue() can actually throw exceptions, and you need to be prepared for this.

So if I understand you correctly - when I call Transform to process the XSLT transformation it will call each of my custom java external functions as needed but the reference to

inputStr = arguments[0].head().getStringValue();

could generate an exception?

I would then need to do something within the java function to force it to get the value - or would I let the exception propogate back to the calling Transformation and catch it there ?

Dave